# Could not find function "bsActionButton"

Tags: r, shiny

My Shiny codes were working fine and now suddenly when I run the App I am getting Error as

> "could not find function "bsActionButton"

I have verified that `Shiny` and `ShinyBS` packages are present but still getting this error. Can anyone help me out on this issue?

Comment: see http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/reference.html

Comment: It did wrk Andry.Thank you thanks a lot.

Comment: probably the function you are looking for is `bsButton` with type = 'action'

Comment: Its not giving me action to mark your post as answer can make the changes required.

Comment: put some example code please

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.61 (Bootstrap3 Initial Release)

[Change log](http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/changes.html)

> bsActionButton and bsToggleButton were replaced by bsButton with a type argument.